# Logical OR in pyomo to force consecutive assignment

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I want to optimise my model that finds the highest possible overlap (`assignment`) of items (`probes`) against a sequence (`sequence`). I have the starting and end positions of all items and can thus build up my model as follows:

```py
import pyomo
import pyomo.environ as pe
import pyomo.opt as po

sequence = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
probes = ["a", "b", "c"]
probe_starts = {"a": 0, "b": 2, "c": 3}
probe_ends = {"a": 2, "b": 4, "c": 5}

# Model definition
model = pe.ConcreteModel()
model.sequence = pe.Set(initialize=sequence)
model.probes = pe.Set(initialize=probes)
model.starts = pe.Param(model.probes, initialize=probe_starts)
model.ends = pe.Param(model.probes, initialize=probe_ends)
model.assignment = pe.Var(model.sequence, model.probes, domain=pe.Binary)

# Objective
expr = sum([model.assignment[j, i] for j in model.sequence for i in model.probes])
model.objective = pe.Objective(expr=expr, sense=pe.maximize)
```

I now have the following three constraints:

- Items can only bind one at a time (no overlapping items)
- Because items have a start and end position they are limited in only getting assigned after their respective starts and ends
- If items are assigned, they have to bind in their entirety spanning from their start to their end

```py
# One probe per sequence position
model.one_probe_bound = pe.ConstraintList()
for s in model.sequence:
    model.one_probe_bound.add(sum(model.assignment[s, p] for p in model.probes) <= 1)

# No assignment before/after start/end
model.define_length = pe.ConstraintList()
for s in model.sequence:
    for p in model.probes:
        if s < model.starts[p]:
            model.define_length.add(model.assignment[s, p] == 0)
        if s > model.ends[p]:
            model.define_length.add(model.assignment[s, p] == 0)
```

Both of the constraints above work without issue but I can't find a way to input the logical or from my third condition. I tried to use the disjunction as described in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030173/how-to-model-logical-or-or-quantifiers-in-pyomo-constraints):

```py
# Only allow full assignment or none
def disjunct_rule(b, p, i):
    m = b.model()
    expr = sum(m.assignment[s, p] for s in m.sequence)
    if i:
        return expr == m.ends[p] - m.starts[p]
    else:
        return expr == 0

def disjunction_rule(m, p):
    return [m.disjunct[p, i] for i in [True, False]]

def xfrm(m):
    pe.TransformationFactory("gdp.bigm").apply_to(m)

model.disjunct = pyomo.gdp.Disjunct(model.probes, [True, False], rule=disjunct_rule)
model.disjunction = pyomo.gdp.Disjunction(model.probes, rule=disjunction_rule)
model.xfrm = pe.BuildAction(rule=xfrm)
```

Looking at the matrix representation of `model.assignment` with `sequence` along the columns and `probes` along the rows, I get the following:

```py
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

As can be seen above, I get assignments that aren't spanning the entire length of the item (e.g. c / 3rd item is only assigned at the last position whereas it should have to bind at the two previous ones too. The only valid solution I can see in this toy example is the following:

```py
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Where items a and c are selected in their entirety and b isn't selected at all. This way we have all constraints matched. The solver I used was `glpk`. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you edit your post and more clearly define your intent (with a couple of examples) for the 3rd constraint, and maybe a representation of a complete legal solution?  It isn't clear what you mean by "items can only bind completely."  It seems you are looking for assignments of 1 probe to 1 position in the sequence and each probe has a set of legal possible assignments.  After that...confusion.

Comment: I added the output I expect in my example. I hope this gives some more clarity.

Comment: ahhh.. OK.  I think you're going to need to reformulate and either add a binary variable for each point in the sequence for "connected" or do something with the end-points, which is likely more efficient....

Comment: Hmm. This is most likely by no means the most efficient way of approaching the problem. Wouldn't another binary variable be somewhat redundant to the `assignment` - or do you mean only using `pe.Var(model.sequence)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a cut at this....

The other way I mentioned would be to introduce another binary variable for each point in sequence and control that (somehow) via the assignment of probes.  The method below should be *much* more efficient than that.

Try this out with a larger dataset...  The current only has 1 feasible solution.  Also, I *assumed* that better solutions would use fewer probes, so I re-wrote the objective to that.

The basis of this solution is the constraint that you must connect to the start once (constraint 1) and the end (constraint 2) once.  And any intermediate connections must be consistent (constraint 3).

I used some sub-setting in a few spots where needed.

#### Code:

```
# model to make contiguous connections across a sequence
# using as few connections (probes) as possible

import pyomo
import pyomo.environ as pe

sequence = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
probes = ["a", "b", "c"]
probe_starts = {"a": 0, "b": 2, "c": 3}
probe_ends = {"a": 2, "b": 4, "c": 5}

# Model definition
model = pe.ConcreteModel()
model.sequence = pe.Set(initialize=sequence)
model.probes = pe.Set(initialize=probes)
model.starts = pe.Param(model.probes, initialize=probe_starts)
model.ends = pe.Param(model.probes, initialize=probe_ends)

model.assign = pe.Var(model.probes, domain=pe.Binary)  # 1 if probe p is used...

# Objective
obj = sum(model.assign[p] for p in model.probes) # use as few as possible...?
model.objective = pe.Objective(expr=obj, sense=pe.minimize)

# Constraints

# must connect start once
model.C1 = pe.Constraint(expr=sum(model.assign[p] for p in model.probes 
    if model.starts[p] == sequence[0]) == 1)

# must connect end once
model.C2 = pe.Constraint(expr=sum(model.assign[p] for p in model.probes 
    if model.ends[p] == sequence[-1]) == 1)

# must connect any intermediate connections...
# if probe p1 is selected, must select an eligible p2 follow on
def connect(model, p1):
    # create subset on the fly of legal follow-on connections
    # assumption here that sequence is a sequential list of ints by using the "+1"
    p2s = [p for p in model.probes if model.starts[p] == model.ends[p1] + 1]
    if not p2s:
        return pe.Constraint.Skip
    return sum(model.assign[p2] for p2 in p2s) == model.assign[p1]

non_completing_probes = [p for p in model.probes if model.ends[p] != sequence[-1]]
model.C3 = pe.Constraint(non_completing_probes, rule=connect)

solver = pe.SolverFactory('glpk')
result = solver.solve(model)
print(result)

model.display()
```

#### Yields:

```
Problem: 
- Name: unknown
  Lower bound: 2.0
  Upper bound: 2.0
  Number of objectives: 1
  Number of constraints: 4
  Number of variables: 4
  Number of nonzeros: 5
  Sense: minimize
Solver: 
- Status: ok
  Termination condition: optimal
  Statistics: 
    Branch and bound: 
      Number of bounded subproblems: 0
      Number of created subproblems: 0
  Error rc: 0
  Time: 0.006771087646484375
Solution: 
- number of solutions: 0
  number of solutions displayed: 0

Model unknown

  Variables:
    assign : Size=3, Index=probes
        Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
          a :     0 :   1.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
          b :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
          c :     0 :   1.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary

  Objectives:
    objective : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Active : Value
        None :   True :   2.0

  Constraints:
    C1 : Size=1
        Key  : Lower : Body : Upper
        None :   1.0 :  1.0 :   1.0
    C2 : Size=1
        Key  : Lower : Body : Upper
        None :   1.0 :  1.0 :   1.0
    C3 : Size=1
        Key : Lower : Body : Upper
          a :   0.0 :  0.0 :   0.0
```

Comment: Awesome! I just tested it on a slightly larger set with a few more probes and it seems to pick the right ones. I'll only get to benchmarking it on a significantly larger dataset (~5k probes and 4k sequence) tomorrow and will add the information below.

Comment: How did it go with the larger set?

Comment: It worked in terms of speed but I incorrectly created this dummy dataset to not properly match the large one. I have gaps between one probe's end and the next one's start and they don't start/end at the sequences start/end. I'm currently trying to find a way with your suggested `model.assign` only which seems to work but I'm getting a suboptimal solution.

Comment: That sounds odd.  Be **sure** to check the solver status.  If it isn’t optimal, you have other problems.  If you are stuck  and can replicate the problem with a reasonable dataset, of course you can re-post another question.

Comment: I was able to find a solution that works in all cases but it's a quadratic expression. Solving the modified toy dataset with `coinbonmin` worked but scaling it up to more values is as slow as you would expect quadratic solving to be. I'll create another question now and leave it here in the comments. Thanks already for your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72231192/linearize-optimization-of-non-overlapping-items-along-a-sequence

Comment: Uggh.  I don't think the problem was well described.  Obviously, for the flow-balance constraint above, "gaps" are a non-starter.

Comment: Yup :(. The question I originally posted here was answered the way you did but the dummy example missed some important details.